# trouble connecting to ServerSocket over the internet

Tags: java, sockets, serversocket

hello guys I've created a simple chat room app but I can't connect to server to send and receive data, here is part of my code:

server side:

```
import java.io.DataInputStream;
import java.io.DataOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.ServerSocket;
import java.net.Socket;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;

public class Listener {

public static void start() {
    try {
        final ServerSocketChannel serverSocketChannel = ServerSocketChannel.open();
        serverSocketChannel.configureBlocking(true);
        serverSocketChannel.socket().bind(new InetSocketAddress(GetConfigs.getServerListenerPort()));
        final List<Operator> operators = new ArrayList<>();
        final int nOperators = 64;
        for (int i = 0; i < nOperators; i++) {
            operators.add(i, new Operator());
        }
        final int parallelism = Runtime.getRuntime().availableProcessors();
        ForkJoinPool pool = new ForkJoinPool(parallelism);
        pool.submit(() -> new Thread(() -> {
            int i = 0;
            while (true) {
                try {
                    operators.get(i).newOperation(serverSocketChannel.accept());
                    i++;
                    if (i == nOperators) {
                        i = 0;
                    }
                } catch (IOException ignored) {
                }
            }
        })).fork().invoke().start();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        Logging.log.error(e);
    }
}
```

client side :

```
import java.io.DataInputStream;
import java.io.DataOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.InetAddress;
import java.net.Socket;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.LinkedList;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;

public class ConnectServer {

private static final String SERVER_ADDRESS = GetConfigs.getServerIPAddress();
private static final int SERVER_LISTENER_PORT = GetConfigs.getServerListenerPort();

private StringBuilder result = new StringBuilder();

private void connect() {
    result.delete(0, result.length());
    try {
        SocketChannel socketChannel = SocketChannel.open();
        socketChannel.configureBlocking(true);
        if (socketChannel.connect(new InetSocketAddress(InetAddress.getByName(SERVER_ADDRESS), SERVER_LISTENER_PORT))) {
            DataOutputStream dos = new DataOutputStream(socketChannel.socket().getOutputStream());
            DataInputStream dis = new DataInputStream(socketChannel.socket().getInputStream());
            dos.writeUTF("...");
            result.append(String.valueOf(dis.readUTF()));
            dos.close();
            dis.close();
            socketChannel.close();
        }
    } catch (IOException ex) {
        //...
    }
}

}
```

It does work on a LAN connection.

please help me...

Comment: Are you in a proxy network?

Comment: It does work on a LAN connection...

Comment: That means your code is correct, you need to check how you will configure your network in your program.

Comment: Just a comment here, but you might wanna consider not using ARM to manage the sockets. The server will close the client socket as soon as it passes the last line in the try statement with the accept().

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Does the error appear in client or server application?

Maybe this could help you:

- Disable your firewall
- Check if any other application uses the port (maybe change port)
- Just an idea: Try it without lambda, it was just released and sometimes errors occur (e.g. in persistence)

Best regards

Comment: In another comment you said it works in LAN. Like @Vishrant said, the code isn't the problem. What is "between" your server and your client? Did you open the port in your router?